# Show that $f(x)=1-x^2, x>0$ and $f(x)=x^2-1,x\leq 0$ is discontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2-1&x\leq 0\\1-x^2& x>0\\\end{cases}$ is discontinuous.

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$

then there are two cases, either $\delta\geq 1$ or $\delta<1$

If $\delta> 1$

then $1\in (0,\delta)$

thus $\vert 1-1^2-(-1)\vert=1> \frac{1}{2}$

If $\delta\leq1$

Then if $y\in (0,\delta)$
$\vert 1-y^2+1\vert>\vert1-\delta^2+1\vert\geq \vert 1-1^2+1\vert=1>\frac{1}{2}$

Thus for any $\delta>0$, there exists a $y\in(0,\delta)$ such that $\vert f(y)-f(0)\vert>\epsilon$, so $f$ is discontinuous.

Does this work? It seems odd, I'm not sure if there is a "cleaner" way to do this, the cases seem odd.

Comment: Yes, what you have done is correct. Nothing odd about it except that inequality $|1-y^{2}+1| > |1-\delta^{2}+1|$ becomes clearer if you remove the absolute value sign.

Comment: I can remove the absolute value since $1-y^2>0$ right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: You don't need to consider the case of $\delta >1$ if you've proven that the case of $\delta \leq 1$ itself leads to a problem. For the continuity of a function, $f$ to hold at a point, $a$, it needs to be the case that, for each $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ s.t. whenever, $|x-a|< \delta$, $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. In the $\delta\leq 1$ case of your solution, you have shown that there exists always a $y$ s.t. $|y-0|<\delta$ but $|f(y)-f(0)|\geq 1/2$. If you plug in $\delta=1$ into this argument, you can cover $\delta>1$ too, as $|y-0|<1< \delta$ for the counterexample $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(0^+)=1,f(0^-)=-1 \implies f(0^+) \ne f(0^-)$$ So there is a jump discontinuity at $x=0$. so $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Does the logic of my proof work though?